# How can I save MATLAB workspace with java objects?

Tags: java, matlab

When I try to save it says "can't write file", and I'm pretty sure it's because I have a ton of java objects laced throughout various structures, etc.  I don't even care about saving these, but excising them all from my workspace is nearly impossible.  Sometimes it works and just gives a bunch of warnings, but at the moment I'm stuck.  I know I have permissions and disk space.  Anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB's [SAVE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command lets you list the variables you wish to save. So, if you only want to save `x`, `y`, and `q`, you can do:

```
save mydata.mat x y q
```

Comment: I've got hundreds of variables.  I prefer to save my workspace so I don't get burned, missing something I need.  In this case, I learned that matlab is happy so long as no java objects are at the top level.  It turns out I had one hanging around in 'ans'.  Once I cleared that, it would save with only warnings.